# Can I connect a Xbox One Wireless Controller to Windows 10 with an ordinary BT dongle?

Tags: controllers, windows-10

I already have an ordinary Bluetooth 4.0 dongle and the official dongle is kind of overpriced with 30€. So the question is, do I need the official one or will any Bluetooth dongle suffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a supported controller and an up-to-date Windows 10, yes - any bluetooth will work. [See Option 3 on this article](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/accessories/connect-xbox-one-controller-to-pc), or [more troubleshooting details here](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/accessories/connect-and-troubleshoot-xbox-one-bluetooth-issues-windows-10).